# How to implement TLS 1.3 in Java Spring boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tls1.3

I want to implement TLS 1.3 in my spring boot application.

https://blog.gypsyengineer.com/en/security/an-example-of-tls-13-client-and-server-on-java.html

In this blog i have seen that TLS 1.3 can be used only with Java 11.. is that true?

Please give me step by step proceduce to implement it.

Comment: Please provide more details. Do you want to write it over HTTP?

Comment: The link you provided already has a sample.

Comment: @John Hi John.. i am completely new to TLS.. as per my knowledge, TLS is HTTP with secure layer. When i hit this webservice, then it should be with HTTPS.

Comment: and i am really sorry, i dont see the sample in that link :( or am i missing something there? :( could you please help?

Answer (score 15):

If you want just TLSv1.3 in your Spring Boot application, you can configure this in your `application.properties` file (or any properties/yml file that is part of an active profile).

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
```

The `server.ssl.enabled-protocols` property takes a list, so if you want TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3, you can do that as well:

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```

A comprehensive guide to configuring SSL/TLS in Spring Boot [can be found here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl), in the documentation. All of the SSL/TLS properties [can be found in this appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) in the documentation.

And to answer your question, yes, TLSv1.3 was delivered in Java 11.

Comment: Hi Todd, Thanks for the response... I have configured it

`server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store-password=secret
server.ssl.key-alias=server
server.ssl.key-password=secret


# SSL protocol to use.
server.ssl.protocol=TLS

# Enabled SSL protocols.
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.3
`


i have followed the same process that has been mentioned in this link

https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/spring-boot-applications-tls-http2/

Comment: I copied the server.jks file in src/main/resources path . but i am getting the following error.

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jsse.alias_no_key_entry
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
 at `
Any idea what the scenarios i will get this error??

Comment: @sandeep It's hard to answer questions in comments here. This looks like something about your setup, I'd recommend adding another question and providing all the detail you can.